# How to send unsigned short int values through xml

Tags: gcc, libxml2

I have to use xml to send utf-16(Ex: 0x123,0x145) data. I am new to xml and we are using libxml2 library. I am able to add string data(Ex: 123456) and get that child node data. I am struck how to send a unsgined short int data through xml. I am using GCC compiler and libxml2 library on ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 2):

XML only supports textual data and no binary data. This means that you have to serialize numbers as strings when writing XML, for example in decimal or hexadecimal notation.

Comment: If I pass any unicode characters, by default XML gives me utf-8 data. So I have a converter which converts the UTF-8 to UTF-16. I am using ICU library for that. I think my problem solved as of now